# Craeating wordArt style by as3

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

Currently I was asked by my Client to Display Curved Fonts lie word art and customize some of the Text fields with this Font.Can we Load the WordArt directly into Fash Textfield?can we Do it by Embedding or any technique (purely with Scripting)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no such thing in AS3. A good way to do it would be to create a text field and switch around the pictures inside of it using code

```
imgbtn1.onRelease = function() {
infoField._visible = true;
startLoading("picture1.jpg");
};
imgbtn2.onRelease = function() {
infoField._visible = true;
startLoading("picture2.jpg");
};
imgbtn3.onRelease = function() {
infoField._visible = true;
startLoading("picture3.jpg");
};
function startLoading(whichImage) {
loadMovie(whichImage, "imageLoader");
_root.onEnterFrame = function() {
infoLoaded = imageLoader.getBytesLoaded();
infoTotal = imageLoader.getBytesTotal();
percentage = Math.floor(infoLoaded/infoTotal*100);
infoField.text = percentage+"%";
if (percentage>=100) {
delete this.onEnterFrame;
infoField._visible = false;
}
};
}
```

Comment: Hi,thanks for ur response...but can u explain briefly..cant v do this by as3 coding????...how can i dynamically apply word art to the text???...thanks in advance.